# Incompatible types when adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, incompatibletypeerror

I am getting an incompatible types error when trying to add something to my arraylist. I can't seem to find out how to fix it, so here I am to ask you guys. This is the code where it goes wrong, hopefully someone has an answer for me! I know the indentation isn't correct here, but it's my first time posting here to bear with me!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Dienblad {
    private ArrayList<Artikel> artikelen;
    private double artikelprijs;
    private double totaalprijs;
    private int artikelaantal;
    /**
     * Constructor
    */
    public Dienblad() {
        artikelen = new ArrayList<Artikel>();
        int artikelaantal = getAantalArtikelen();
        double totaalprijs = 0;
    }
    /**
    * Methode om artikel aan dienblad toe te voegen
    ** @param artikel
    */
    public void voegToe(Artikel artikel , double artikelPrijs) {
        artikelen.add(artikel);
        totaalprijs = totaalprijs + artikelPrijs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be ok, can you post your error?

Comment: What's the exact and complete error message? Which line of which fil does it refer to?

Comment: one thing that is wrong in your code is that you assign values to new local variables in your constructor. This will not fix the problem you describe, but it will help you in the future. Change `int artikelaantal = getAantalArtikelen();` to `artikelaantal = getAantalArtikelen();` and `double totaalprijs = 0;` to `totaalprijs = 0;`

Comment: When I create an object with BlueJ all is fine. The problem arrises when I call the method voegToe and try to add an artikel. It only says Error: incomparable types. The terminal doesnt show me anything else. I changed the variables as you said but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine.
Do you by any chance have two instances of Artikel defines in different packages (by mistake) ?

Comment: Well I do have a different class named Artikel, but I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: I think this might be your problem. If you have two different classes, eg: com.xyz.Artikel and com.abc.Artikel, java will consider them as different classes. Make sure that your are importing the same package in both the places in your code. Or write the entire path private ArrayList<com.xyz.Artikel> artikelen; and make sure its the same class object that you are trying to put in the array list